# How to refresh changes done manually to main.tf in terraform?

Tags: terraform, refresh

So i have a situation in which, I performed following steps,

1. I created a git repo using terraform which has description - ***My first repo using terraform***
2. Now on github, I have manually changed description to - ***Description changed manually***
3. I ran `terraform refresh` so now my state file has updated description of repo
4. But when I do terraform apply, it again changes to - ***My first repo using terraform***
5. So rather than doing changes manually in main.tf file, is there any way I can take changes to main.tf file the same way I did for statefile?

Comment: Sorry, but you question is unclear. Please provide full details of what you are doing? "same way I did for statefile" - what does it mean? What changes you made to statefile? How? Manually?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make terraform update your main.tf based on the state file. When you  run "terraform apply" it is always going to assume main.tf is your desired state and update to reflect that.

Comment: I see, this is kind of bad in a way but again it forces to do any changes using infrastructure as code method so maybe it's good also. 

Thank you for your answer!!